# How would I send AJAX requests faster

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to send AJAX requests right at the same time. I tried using a for loop

```
for(i = 0;i <= 10; i ++){
    $.get("http://search.roblox.com/catalog/json?CatalogContext=1&SortType=0&SortAggregation=3&SortCurrency=0&LegendExpanded=true&Category=0", function(r){
        var date = new Date();
        console.log(date.getTime());
    });
}
```

However, they are not sent at the same time, and there are noticeable differences between the times logged. I want to basically send them AT THE SAME TIME as each other (if that's possible). 
I was wondering if there was any method to do such a thing?

Comment: The A in AJAX means ASYNCHRONOUS.

Comment: You would have to either use http2 (which isn't supported by many servers at this time), or, use subdomains to get around the browser's max concurrent requests per domain limit.

Comment: Browsers will only make a certain number of concurrent requests to a particular domain. http://sgdev-blog.blogspot.com/2014/01/maximum-concurrent-connection-to-same.html

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Why not send 1 request a script that performs many functions?

Comment: It doesn't really matter what im trying to accomplish. Basically what I want to do is send as many requests in a given time as possible. And its the same domain, yes. Just atleast give me something that's quicker than a for loop or setinterval

Comment: Nothing will be quicker than a for loop, the for loop isn't what is limiting you.

Comment: Not true @Kevin. Simply by putting a for loop inside a for loop i managed to make it quicker already.

Comment: No you didn't, the browser will still only allow x concurrent requests per second, with x being far less than how many a single for loop can send in a second.

Comment: @ZimbabweElephant you should investigate your Web Servers configuration. For Apache, if `MaxClients` is set to 10, you will only be able to establish 10 socket connections with the web server before they are queued to wait for a open socket.

Comment: besides the fact that putting a for loop inside a for loop doesn't make anything faster.

Comment: @KevinB not true, it drops performance at an increasing rate!

Comment: @ZimbabweElephant it does matter what you're trying to accomplish. If we know this, someone may be able to offer a better solution or optimize what you're using to work better.

Comment: If you want to send requests at same time, you have to set up a concurrent system with multiple threads, invoking at the same time (clock synchronized). The Javascript itself doesn't support it since it's single threaded. Try that test on another language platform that supports multithreading.

Comment: @KarelG not quite, while JavaScript only operates on a single thread, you can spawn web workers to create different processes.

Comment: Web workers is not only limited, it creates a fake multi-threaded environment if you look to it from other languages' perspective like C#. I see these as "background workers". Setting up a new thread is something different IMO.

Comment: would a worker even get around the  max concurrent requests to a single origin problem?

Comment: @KevinB no, if each of the workers generated a new HTTP request at the same time, they would establish unique socket connection to the web server, which would handle them as individual requests and would keep them as `ESTABLISHED` until the content is passed to the client. Since the request is a static JSON file, the connection would close once the file is completely transferred to the client. My test was 334 MS. Depends on the server settings, but enough connections would result in DoS.

Comment: As a warning, please do not insult others. These comments have been removed.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
@*!!!!!!!!!! added to routes routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");!!!!!!!*@
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            width: 300px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>


    <div class="aSpinner" style="display: none;" onclick="">
        <img src="~/Content/ajax_busy2.gif" title="Please wait.... Contacting server for action..." />
        ...Please wait.... Contacting server for action...
    </div>
    <div id="divMore"></div>

    <div>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            $(".aSpinner").show();

             $.when(
                    $.get("/Main/Index01", function (html01) {
                        $("#divMore").append(html01);
                    }),
                    $.get("/Main/Index02", function (html02) {
                        $("#divMore").append(html02);
                    }),
                    $.get("/Main/Index03")
                        ).then(function () {
                            // All is ready now, so...
                            $("#divMore").append("all three call done aynchronously");
                        });
        </script>


    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

ously");

```
    public class MainController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Main/

        public string Index01()
        {
            return "index01";
        }

        public string Index02()
        {
            return "index02";
        }

        public string Index03()
        {
            return "index03";
        }
```

[image]
                        });

Comment: the last get seems to have a problem with argument passing, maybe the last call in the chain is different

Comment: This answer is not complete nor is it tested. Please review: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/

Comment: give complete credit to https://css-tricks.com/multiple-simultaneous-ajax-requests-one-callback-jquery/

Comment: The article discusses waiting till a 3 AJAX requests are completed before presenting the results. *In our simple use case, we can use jQuery's `$.when()` method, which takes a list of these "Deferred" objects (All jQuery Ajax methods return Deferred objects) and then provides a single callback.* It's hard to tell if this solution would answer OP's question since the question is not clear and we do not know what he is trying to achieve.